# Can I import psycopg2 in postgresql source code?

Tags: python, c, postgresql

I'm writing a contrib of postgresql and I want to use PyImport_ImportModule to import a python module, which imports psycopg2.

Then I find that PyImport_ImportModule returns null, if I import psycopg2 in the python code.

Could someone please tell me why or how to solve it?

This is my C code,

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "postgres.h"

PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"%s\")", CODE_PATH);
PyObject *pModule = NULL;
pModule = PyImport_ImportModule(MODULE_NAME);
if (pModule == NULL)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    elog(ERROR, "could not import module %s", code_file_name);
}
```

and this is my python code,

```
from typing import List
import psycopg2

# Global variables
CONNECTIONS = {}
CURSORS = {}
EXECUTED = {}


def init_connection(id: int):
    global CONNECTIONS, CURSORS, EXECUTED
    # Initialize the connection to the remote database with the given id if it does not exist
    if id not in CURSORS:
        CONNECTIONS[id] = psycopg2.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1",
            port=5432,
            user="lucky",
            password="",
            database="test",
        )
        CURSORS[id] = CONNECTIONS[id].cursor()
        EXECUTED[id] = False


def get_remote_tuple(query: str, id: int) -> List[str]:
    global CURSORS, EXECUTED

    # find the result set of query with the given id
    # if it exists, return the next tuple
    # otherwise, execute the query and store the result set in the dictionary

    if id not in CURSORS:
        init_connection(id)
    cursor = CURSORS[id]
    if not EXECUTED[id]:
        cursor.execute(query)
        EXECUTED[id] = True

    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        del CONNECTIONS[id]
        del CURSORS[id]
        del EXECUTED[id]
        return None
    return list(map(str, result))


def reset_remote_tuple(query: str, id: int):
    global CURSORS, EXECUTED
    # reset the result set of query with the given id
    # if it exists, clear the result set and execute the query again
    # otherwise, execute the query
    if id not in CURSORS:
        init_connection(id)
    cursor = CURSORS[id]
    if not EXECUTED[id]:
        cursor.execute(query)
        EXECUTED[id] = True
    else:
        cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute(query)


def format_transform(value: str, type: int) -> str:
    # Implement the transformation logic here
    # based on the target database format
    return value
```

Comment: please include some code. I suspect you have a circular import - there are ways to do circular imports in python, but it leads to problems if you try to execute code at import-time

Comment: I have added my code into the question body. Sorry for the latency.

Comment: That is a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with the problem yet crucial parts are missing, that is not runnable C code. Please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example